# Imports in Scala

Tags: scala

I am stuck with the below code:

```
trait Service extends Closeable {
  class STATE(value: Int, statename: String) extends Eumeration(value: Int, statename: String) {
    val NOTINITED =  Value(0, "NOTINITED")
    val INITED = Value(1, "INITED")
    val STARTED = Value(2, "STARTED")
    val STOPPED = Value(3, "STOPPED")
    override def toString() = statename
    type STATE = Value
  }
}
```

Then I have created a new class

```
import abc.event.Service

class ServiceStateModel(name: String) {
  val statemap: Array[Array[Boolean]] = Array(
    Array(false, true,  false,  true),
    Array(false, true,  true,   true),
    Array(false, false, true,   true),
    Array(false, false, false,  true))
}
```

In above code compiler gives me a warning

```
**Multiple markers at this line
- imported `Service' is permanently hidden by definition of trait Service in package event
- imported `Service' is permanently hidden by definition of trait Service in package event**
```

As a result I have renamed the `Service` to `SS` via below import:

```
import abc.event.{Service => SS}
```

But now `SS` is not even recognized

P.S I have hadoop libs in my classpath and it has an interface called `Service`, therefore I have imported my own `Service` trait.

Comment: If both ServiceStateModel and Service are in the same package abc.event, then just remove the line import abc.event.Service

Comment: What packages are your `Service` and `ServiceStateModel` in?

Comment: Got some finding that Class STATE is not visible

I can do 
class ServiceStateModel(name:String, state:SS)

but not 
class ServiceStateModel(name:String, state:SS.STATE) 

Please assist how can achieve : class ServiceStateModel(name:String, state:SS.STATE)

Comment: The reason I have used import is, I have libs of Hadoop in my classpath which has Service class, as a result I have to put import

Comment: Also how can I achieve something like below we do in java     Service.STATE.NOTINITED

Comment: Please post more of the source so we can see the package layouts.